# Can an declare-styleable attribute be fully qualified in a style (to avoid naming conflicts)?

Tags: android

**In the below style, can `button_csl` be fully qualified with the styleable from which it is defined in, as**

```
<item name="com.inc.app.LabeledButton:button_csl">@color/button_bar_csl_white</item>
```

**for example, so that it doesn't potentially conflict with another attribute?**

```
<!--ImageView-->
<style name="ButtonBar_LabeledButton_NavBar" parent="ButtonBar_LabeledButton">    
  <item name="com.inc.app:button_csl">@color/button_bar_csl_white</item>    
</style>
```

The attribute `button_csl` is defined in the following styleable

```
<declare-styleable name="LabeledButton">
  <attr name="button_csl" format="reference"></attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

However if a new styleable is declared that had the same attribute, how is conflict resolved?

```
<declare-styleable name="NewStyleableButton">
  <attr name="button_csl" format="reference"></attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

This doesn't seem to be an issue when reading attributes, since they are scoped to the specific styleable (ie, `Resource.Styleable.LabeledButton_button_csl`)

```
private void ReadAttributes(Context context, IAttributeSet attributes)
{
    Android.Content.Res.TypedArray typedArray = context.ObtainStyledAttributes(attributes, Resource.Styleable.LabeledButton);

    _button_csl = typedArray.GetResourceId(Resource.Styleable.LabeledButton_button_csl, 0);

    typedArray.Recycle();
}
```

However, for style definitions, there seems to be an ambiguity

```
<!--ImageView-->
<style name="NewButtonStyle">
  <item name="com.inc.app:button_csl">@color/button_bar_csl_white</item>    
</style>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like you can do that, at least from what I can find.

Comment: @TheWanderer Well when the attributes are read, they are used as indices into the `typedArray`, which uses fully qualified name. If this is the only context of usage, then I guess there wouldn't be any other conflicts.